# linux shell script: how to compare the value of a script command to an integer

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, I create a shell script `number1.sh` takes a file as an argument and prints the bytes of the file. Now, I have another shell script `number2.sh` which also takes a file as argument, and in this shell script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash 7    
fileByte="./number1.sh $1"
if [ "$fileByte" -eq 0 ] 
then
.....
```

I want to compare the print result of the command `./number1.sh $1` to the integer 0, but in this case `"$fileByte"` is `./number1.sh`, how should I proceed?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Please include your code to make it clear. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for number1.sh #!/bin/bash wc -c $1

Comment: for number2.sh #!/bin/bash fileByte="./number1.sh $1" if [ "$fileByte" - eq 0] then do  ......

Comment: ./number1.sh filename will print a value, I just want to compare this value to 0 in number2.sh in the if statement

Comment: `fileByte=$(./number1.sh $1)`

Comment: Thanks!! This works for me!